# Interpreting contradicting Dickey-Fuller results

Tags: augmented-dickey-fuller

I am getting some contradicting results for an ADF unit root test (attached), with two rejecting H0 and two not. How should I interpret these results? Would it be possible to calculate the actual DF test statistic (tau) or the estimated coefficient (gamma) based on this output?

For an ADF unit root test model, H0:gamma=0, H1:gamma<0 where gamma is the estimated coefficient. The test statistic (tau) is calculated as DF tau = gamma (est) / SE (gamma) from which p can be determined; I think the four test statistics are based on different estimations of tau, but not sure. What I am actually mostly interested in is how to derive the estimation of the coefficient gamma.

I cannot add any comments, but yes I am working with a panel dataset

[image: Dickey-Fuller results]

Comment: It is not clear what hypotheses the four test statistics correspond to. Could you elaborate on that? Could you show us the test equation(s)?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: What you have run there is a panel unit root test, not a unit root test. Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question. ***You will be able to edit your question & comment on it, when you register & merge your accounts.***